# Sublime Text 2 - Prevent console from opening when compiling (Ctrl + B)

Tags: compilation, console, sublimetext2

I'm using Less Build tool to compile my less files to css, but every time i compile it automatically opens the console. I can resize the console but i can't collapse it entirely. Is it possible to prevent the console from opening when compiling something? If i need the console open i'll just open it from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Escape` key to completely close the console. This doesn't help you with prohibiting it from showing up at all in the first place, but if that option doesn't exist then this is probably the next best thing.

Comment: That's seems a little excessive though. I guess i'll just have to get used to it! After using it for a while i realized it isn't always useless, it tells me exactly where syntax errors appear etc; not that bad. The console is still annoying though, as i have a rather small screen and i would prefer to utilize that space in a better way.